# Attiny85 PINB is randomly blinking

Tags: c++, avr, attiny

I`m trying to figure out how to work with attiny85 and I stuck with an issue.

I use rgb led strip to indicate bits (1 pixel - 1 bit, I found it very convenient).
All the code is:

```
#define F_CPU 8388608UL // 8MH

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>


#define LED PB4


void setBitHigh(short int pin) {
    PORTB |= _BV(pin); // 1 tactDuration = 125*10-9sec
    asm("nop");
    asm("nop");
    asm("nop");
    asm("nop");
    asm("nop");

    PORTB &= ~_BV(pin); // 1 tactDuration
    asm("nop");
    asm("nop");
}

void setBitLow(short int pin) {
    PORTB |= _BV(pin); // 1 tactDuration
    asm("nop");
    asm("nop");

    PORTB &= ~_BV(pin); // 1 tactDuration
    asm("nop");
    asm("nop");
    asm("nop");
    asm("nop");
    asm("nop");
}

void trueByte(short int pin, short int intensity) {
    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
        intensity & _BV(i) ? setBitHigh(pin) : setBitLow(pin);
    }
}
void falseByte(short int pin) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        setBitLow(pin);
    }
}

void setPixel(short int pin, short int r, short int g, short int b) {
    g > 0 ? trueByte(pin, g) : falseByte(pin);
    r > 0 ? trueByte(pin, r) : falseByte(pin);
    b > 0 ? trueByte(pin, b) : falseByte(pin);
}


void indicate(int data) { 
    int tmp = data;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        int intensity = (tmp & _BV(i)) > 0 ? 10 : 0;

        setPixel(LED, intensity, 0, 0);
    }
}

void blink(short int times) {
    for (short int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        indicate(255);
        _delay_ms(200);
        indicate(0);
        _delay_ms(200);
    }
}

int main() {
    DDRB = 0x00 | _BV(LED);
    PORTB = 0x00;

    _delay_ms(1000);
    blink(3);
    _delay_ms(1000);


    while(true) {
        indicate(PINB);
        _delay_ms(50);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I expected the PINB indicator to be `0`(no light at the strip), but it is blinking with some pattern I can not recognise familiar, but I see it cyclic. Only first 4 bits periodically became `1`.

As you can see, I use PB4 only for LED... PB0-3 are free (not connected at all)

I will be glad to any ideas or tips, ty.

Comment: What speed is the CPU running at? Did you change any fuse bits from the factory defaults? Where did that F_CPU value come from (seems non-standard)?

Comment: Try changing the final `_delay_ms(50);` to `_delay_ms(1000);` and see if the LCD does something at the rate you expect.

Comment: I changed fuses to`lfuse = 0xE2; hfuse = 0xDF; efuse = 0xFF` to reach 8MH freq ( because of default freq a 500ms delay longs several seconds).

`#define F_CPU 8388608UL // 8MH = 8 * 1024 * 1024.`.. it was 8000000 when I caught the issue and I tried to change it to more precise

Comment: It was `1000ms` at first, I changed it to `50ms` trying to figure out the pattern of blinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem does not concern sw but hw. This is the normal behavior of an unconnected input pin. An unconnected input pin behaves unpredictably. The inputs **must be driven** by some signal or **pulled** with resistors to VCC or GND. Pull Up can be done with internal resistors. In your program, simply set **PORTB** to **0x0F**

```
int main() {
    DDRB = 0x00 | _BV(LED);
    PORTB = 0x0F;
```

[See DS how MCU ports work](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-2586-avr-8-bit-microcontroller-attiny25-attiny45-attiny85_datasheet.pdf#page=54)

If you want PB0-3 to be 0, you have to pull down with external resistors (10kΩ or similar) to GND.